# Re-Open program once it's closed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a Python script to reopen Outlook once it is closed.

The purpose of this is: basically I have this annoying habit of closing down Outlook once I've finished, and when I close Outlook I won't get any reminders or e-mail notifications.

I managed to make a python script that once you run it, it will open Outlook:

```
import os
outlook = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE'
os.startfile(outlook)
```

How do I  make it so once outlook.exe has been closed, it will open it back up again? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get running process. Once it exit, rerun it.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, it is not very difficult to restart a dead child. You should only think twice about what it implies: you will have to kill you launcher before trying to volutarily stop Outlook.

To directly answer your question, you can use `subprocess` for that:

```
import subprocess
import time

outlook = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE'
while True:
    p = subprocess.Popen(outlook)
    p.wait()  # just wait for the child to end and... restart it immediately
    time.sleep(5)   # unsure if really useful
```

Above code adds a delay before restarting, because I do not know the internals of Outlook (I have not used it for years). If it started subprocesses and if the initial process did not wait for its children, the delay could ensure that every piece of Outlook is gone before starting a new copy. Firefox and Thunderbird for example are known to need some time between the ask for close and a restart.